# What are the charges incurrent for keeping Azure App Insights in one region and the Log Analytics Workspace in another?

Tags: azure-log-analytics, appinsights, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I have my App Insights(Classic) in West US2. I want to move it to workspace based mode. My Log Analytics Workspace is in another region (West US). Is it ok to migrate? What are the pricing impacts pertaining to the resources being in different regions?

Answer (score 0):

- If you already have a workspace in a different region, it is fine but if you want to migrate it to a different region when you already have instances in it. Unfortunately, it is not possible, Microsoft can manually move the region if you want and there won't be any extra pricing if you change the region.
- We have [Azure Mover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/overview) which came into the picture in September 2020 but unfortunately, Application insights don't support it.